# Working code examples for stack or heap buffer overflows?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I understand how this exploits work on the theoretical level, but I can't find detailed worked tutorials that show for example how to overwrite the return adress in the stack when overflowing a given buffer in a given function etc. Is there a database of such shared exploits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exploit-DB](https://www.exploit-db.com/) is a well-known repository for exploit code and includes a number of overflows.  For example, here's one against [socat](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47999) which includes the steps required to exercise the overflow.  Some exploits have more information, some less, but if you browse enough you should find the sort of shared exploit you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@gowenfawr's answer is a good place to start.

However, while practical, many of the PoCs there are not going to be very verbose, since their goal is to exploit rather than teach. The linked socat does explain the steps in depth, but there are jumps in reasoning and assumed knowledge is probably left out; more of the "what" than the "why". If you want someone to explain the concepts, I recommend that you find a CTF problem that involves a buffer overflow, and look at the write-ups for it.